# Php Rest API: problem creating an array separated with ampersands

Tags: php, rest, laravel-5

I have a doubt: An api requests the following structure:

API endpoint

● Production:

```
https://api-cbt.mercadolibre.com/api/orders/search/?days=<recentdays>&status=<order_status>&page=
<pageno>&access_token=xxx
```

● HTTP Method: GET

● Content-type header: content-type:application/json

Consequently I created the following structure:

```
        $variables = [];
        $variables['days'] = 10;
        $variables['page'] = 1;
        $query = $meli->get('/api/orders/search/', $variables, array('access_token' => $token));
```

but for some reason gives HTTPCODE = 401 (this is because $variables and commas are not been considered properly, I know that because access_token work perfect with other API calls).

My main question is what I have to do in order to produce a result like days=&status=&page=.. Im confused because I expected an array to be considered in that way but its not what is going on in my experience.

EDIT------

About GET:

```
/**
 * Execute a GET Request
 *
 * @param string $path
 * @param array $params
 * @param boolean $assoc
 * @return mixed
 */
public function get($path, $params = null, $assoc = false) {
    $exec = $this->execute($path, null, $params, $assoc);

    return $exec;
}
```

the library is provided by [MercadoLibre](https://github.com/mercadolibre/php-sdk) at https://github.com/mercadolibre/php-sdk/blob/master/Meli/meli.php
thanks in advance..

Comment: What library you are using for communication? What is the object `$meli` with method `get()`

Comment: @yergo good point, my mistake. I edited the post. thank you.

Comment: I would start with debugging what's build after [this line](https://github.com/mercadolibre/php-sdk/blob/738cdf5ab4c5a0edc4abea3eb9c34c4cca16f4dd/Meli/meli.php#L288). iT smells like "api" may happen 2 times there. Funny but for the glimpse of code, everything seems legit. Maybe your token is invalid? 401 is "Access Denied".

Comment: thank you, yes I know that 401 refers to token, but using the same token with other post/put/ calls, they are working very nice.. weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would threat `access_token` as a variable to pass within query string:

```
        $variables = [];
        $variables['days'] = 10;
        $variables['page'] = 1;
        $variables['access_token'] => $token;

        $query = $meli->get('/api/orders/search/', $variables)
```

Looking at [`get()`](https://github.com/mercadolibre/php-sdk/blob/738cdf5ab4c5a0edc4abea3eb9c34c4cca16f4dd/Meli/meli.php#L169) it seems that third argument should be boolean, not an array.

Comment: If this works, this is a lol catch. Feel free to delete whole question as it should be closed anyway.